# Angular 4 - Cannot get custom HTTP header in HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular

I have an ASP.NET Web API.  I am using Angular 4 to do a simple http request:

```
getInfo(url: string)
{
    this.http.get<MyResponse>(url).map((resultModel: MyResponse) => {

    return resultModel;
    });
}
```

I subscribe to the response thusly:

```
this.getInfo()
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                if(wasSuccess(result))
                {
                    do things
                },
            error => {
                  if(error.status == 401)
                  {
                        var url = error.headers["x-login_page"];
                        window.location.href = url;
                  }
              }
      );
```

I have enabled CORS in the ASP.NET Web API controller.

Looking at the network response in Chrome I see that the CORS allows are there correctly, and so are the custom header entries (x-login_page) that I want to read:

[Screenshot of Chrome Network Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT2ce.png)

However, when I attempt to access the custom header value for x-login_page using

```
var url = error.headers["x-login_page"];
```

The url is undefined.  When I look at the error object in the Chrome debugger, I see that the error object is an HttpErrorResponse object:

[Screenshot HttpErrorResponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV9DG.png)

If I expand the headers, you can see that they do not in any way resemble the headers shown in the network response:

[Screenshot headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOPuD.png)

I cannot figure out a way to get the actual http headers in the error catch, rather than some substituted header.  Open to any and all suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HttpErrorResponse isn't just an array, it is a complex object. To get your url, use its `get` method.

`var url = error.headers.get("x-login_page")`

Comment: No problem! If you aren't using an IDE with autocomplete, it isn't very obvious. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer if it worked for you ;)